# open object in PowerBuilder by API function

Tags: api, powerbuilder

Is it possible to open in PowerBuilder editor a object (Window, UserObject Function etc) by API function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PowerBuilder accepts command line arguments for the workspace, painter, and object to open. See the PowerBuilder help for Command Line Arguments.

For example in PB 12.5
`pb125 /w D:\proj\myapp.pbw /P dataw /O d_order_entry` opens the `myapp` workspace and opens `d_order_entry` in the DataWindow painter

The /P argument just needs the first few characters of the painter name, enough to uniquely identify it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of an actual official API, but there is a hacky / tricky technique that is used by the tool Visual Expert to open an object in the IDE:

- add an item to the todo list, that can include the reference of an object (the items of the todo list are in the registry, for example `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sybase\PowerBuilder\11.5\Target\c:$Dev$path_of_the_project$project.pbt\ToDo`
- then jump to it by simulating the user interaction with some windows messages (call to the `tools / to do list` menu item, search of the correct target and item in the list, and so on)

For what I have seen, you can define precisely an action to perform on the todo list entry, alas it seems also undocumented. Here is an example :  `window:///c|\Dev\path_of_the_project\some_lib.pbl?action=open&entry=w_somewindow&event=open)`